# Fixing security vulnerabilities in docker image

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I have the following docker file

```
FROM debian:stable

# Avoid warnings by switching to noninteractive
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive


#Versions
ENV HELM_VERSION=v3.10.0
ENV KUBECTL_VERSION=v1.20.9
ENV MAVEN_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/cicd/assets/truststore.jks"
ENV TERRAFORM_VERSION=1.2.0
ENV GOLANG_VERSION=1.19.1
ENV TERRAGRUNT_VERSION=v0.38.7
 
RUN set -xe \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN apt-get install zip unzip
#Copy python requirements file
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/pip-tmp/
 
# Makes the Ansible directories
RUN mkdir /etc/ansible /ansible
RUN mkdir ~/.ssh
    
# Configure apt and install python packages
RUN apt-get update -y -q \
    && apt-get upgrade -y -q \
    && apt-get install -y wget \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends apt-utils dialog 2>&1 \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils \
    && apt-get -y install ca-certificates software-properties-common build-essential curl git gettext-base maven sshpass krb5-user \
    && pip --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir install -r /tmp/pip-tmp/requirements.txt \
    && apt-get -y install jq \
    && rm -rf /tmp/pip-tmp 
 
#Install helm
RUN wget https://get.helm.sh/helm-${HELM_VERSION}-linux-amd64.tar.gz \
&& tar -zxvf helm-${HELM_VERSION}-linux-amd64.tar.gz \
&& mv linux-amd64/helm /usr/local/bin/helm
 
#Install kubectl
RUN curl --silent https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/${KUBECTL_VERSION}/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl --output /usr/local/bin/kubectl \
&& chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kubectl
 
#Install Docker CLI
RUN curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh \
&& curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/2.10.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose \
&& chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
 
#Install AWS CLI
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" \
&& unzip awscliv2.zip \
&& ./aws/install
 
#Copy Assets
#RUN mkdir -p /cicd
#COPY assets /cicd
 
#Install helm plugins
#RUN helm plugin add https://github.com/databus23/helm-diff
#RUN helm plugin install /cicd/helm-nexus-push
 
# Downloading gcloud package
RUN curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz > /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
 
# Installing the package
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/gcloud \
  && tar -C /usr/local/gcloud -xvf /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz \
  && /usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
 
# Adding the package path to local
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin
 
RUN cd /tmp && \
    wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${TERRAFORM_VERSION}/terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip && \
    unzip terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip -d /usr/local/bin && \
    rm -rf /tmp/*
 
RUN cd /tmp && \
    wget  https://dl.google.com/go/go${GOLANG_VERSION}.linux-amd64.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzf go${GOLANG_VERSION}.linux-amd64.tar.gz -C /usr/local && \
    rm -rf /tmp/*
 
RUN cd /tmp && \
    wget https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/releases/download/${TERRAGRUNT_VERSION}/terragrunt_linux_amd64 && \
    mv terragrunt_linux_amd64 /usr/local/bin/terragrunt && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/terragrunt && \
    rm -rf /tmp/*
 
RUN git config --global http.sslCAinfo /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
 
ENV GOPATH=/usr/local/go
ENV PATH=/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0
 
RUN go version
 
RUN terraform --version
 
RUN terragrunt --version
 
RUN ansible --version
 
CMD bash
```

I build the docker image and upload it to google artifact registry, but I always come across security vulnerabilities I have tried to fix it but unfortunately I'm unable to fix the security vulnerabilities. Please look at the critical errors and let me know how I can fix this, Any recommendation is appreciated. Thank You.
[image: Security vulnerabilities from Google Artifact Registry]

Comment: Click on the view fix and do the as mentioned in it. Most probably some of them csn not fix.

Comment: *"Any recommendation is appreciated"* - I recommend that you read the CVEs carefully.  It is likely that the problems are that you are using old versions of ... things ... and the solution will be to use a newer version.

Comment: In this case only 3 of them have fixes. Others have not

Comment: Well then ... fix the ones that have fixes, and consider whether the unfixed ones are bad enough that you simply need to abandon trying to use this docker image entirely.

Comment: If you could not apply specific fix. Can help you.

Comment: Well, if you cannot fix the problem, then you need to consider whether it is safe (enough) to run with the vulnerability present.  That is for the OP to decide.  Not us.

Comment: Addy - You have made it difficult for us by pasting the vulnerability information as an image rather than as text.   In future, please copy and paste the details as text.

Comment: Also ... rather than just saying *"vulnerabilities I have tried to fix it but unfortunately I'm unable to fix the security vulnerabilities"* ... tell us what you actually tried.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the DockerFile is trying to a specific version of golang by hand into "/usr/local" rather than using the Debian package manager.  According to the info at https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2021-38297, that bug is fixed in 1.17.3-3 and the Dockerfile are using 1.19.1.  So perhaps there is an old golang installation in the base image ... and that is what the scanner is picking up.  Check that, and if necessary `apt install` a newer version.

Likewise, https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2022-23806 should be fixed by a newer version of golang.  See the CVE link for versions.

https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2015-20107 could be fixed by upgrading to Python 3.10.6-1 or later.

https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2019-19814 doesn't appear to have a fix from upstream, so there is nothing you can do about it except not use f2fs.

https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2022-29599 can be fixed by updating the maven-shared-utils package; see the CVE link for versions.

https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2022-1996 has a fix upstream but it is awaiting triage by the Debian team.

---

In summary, some of the vulnerabilities can be fixed, but for a couple of them no fix is readily available.  So:

- Apply the fixes that are available.
- Then read the CVEs and accompanying explanations and 1) make a judgement whether they represent a risk that you can take, and 2) figure out if you can mitigate the risk; e.g. by locking down access to the running Docker container.

Comment: I always get the https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2015-20107 error, even if i just have this commands for docker file
FROM debian:stable
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    python3.10 \
    python3-pip

Comment: You might need to **uninstall** python3.9.

Comment: I'm facing the same issues but with the node modules although I updated the node and npm versions.